# Field expression not allowed for generic SObject-Error

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am Getting this Error "Field expression not allowed for generic SObject"

**VF CODE**

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="TestPageForRadioCtrl">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:selectRadio value="{!optionSelected}">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!TakeOther}" rerender="tableShow"/>
               <apex:selectoptions value="{!radioValues}" />
            </apex:selectRadio>
            <apex:pageBlockSection Title="Different Radio">
                <apex:outputPanel id="tableShow">
                <apex:pageblockTable value="{!wrap}" var="w">
                    <apex:column value="{!w.id}"/>

                </apex:pageblockTable>
                </apex:outputPanel>



            </apex:pageBlockSection>     
        </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class TestPageForRadioCtrl {

public String optionSelected{get;set;}
public List<Sobject> selectedObj{get;set;}
public List<WrapperClass> wrap{get;set;}
public String type{get;set;}
public String FileName{get;set;}
Integer i=0;
Map <String,Schema.SobjectType> schemaMap=Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
public List<SelectOption> Name
{
    get{

      List<String> gd=new List<String>();
     List<SelectOption> options=new List<SelectOption>();  
     gd.addAll(schemaMap.keySet());
     Schema.DescribeSobjectResult[] results= Schema.describeSobjects(gd);

     for(Schema.DescribeSobjectResult res:results)
     {
         options.add(new SelectOption(res.getName(),res.getLabel()));
     }

     return options;   

    }

 }

public List<SelectOption> radioValues 
    {
        get {
        List<SelectOption> resList = new List<SelectOption>();
        resList.add(new SelectOption('Attachment', 'Attachment'));
        resList.add(new SelectOption('ContentDocument', 'Files'));
         resList.add(new SelectOption('Document', 'Document'));
          resList.add(new SelectOption('StaticResource', 'Static Resource'));
        return resList;
            }
    }


public  TestPageForRadioCtrl(){

     wrap=new List<WrapperClass>(); 
    optionSelected='Attachment';
    selectedObj=Database.query('SELECT Name,Id,BodyLength ,CreatedDate,Owner.Name from '+optionSelected);
    i=0;
    for(Sobject s:selectedObj)
      {
               FileName=String.valueof(s.Name);
               WrapperClass w=new WrapperClass(type,i,false,s.id,FileName,s.BodyLength);
               i++;
               wrap.add(w);

      }

} 

public PageReference TakeOther()
{
    wrap=new List<WrapperClass>();
    system.debug('---In method-----');
    if(optionSelected=='Attachment')
      {    
               wrap=new List<WrapperClass>();
             type=optionSelected;
             i=0;
          selectedObj=Database.query('SELECT Name,Id,BodyLength ,CreatedDate,Owner.Name from '+type);
          for(Sobject s:selectedObj)
          {
               WrapperClass w=new WrapperClass(type,i,false,s.id,s.Name,s.BodyLength);
               wrap.add(w);
              i++;
          }


      } else if(optionSelected=='ContentDocument'){
           wrap=new List<WrapperClass>();
           type=optionSelected;

           system.debug('---Type----'+type);
           selectedObj=Database.query('SELECT Title,Id,ContentSize,CreatedDate,Owner.Name from '+type);
           i=0;
           for(Sobject s:selectedObj)
          {
               WrapperClass w=new WrapperClass(type,i,false,s.id,s.Title,s.ContentSize);
               wrap.add(w);
               i++;

          }
      }  

    else if(optionSelected=='Document'){
            wrap=new List<WrapperClass>();
           type=optionSelected;

           system.debug('---Type----'+type);
          selectedObj=Database.query('SELECT Name,Id,BodyLength ,CreatedDate,Owner.Name from '+type);
          i=0;
          for(Sobject s:selectedObj)
          {
               WrapperClass w=new WrapperClass(type,i,false,s.id,s.Name,s.BodyLength);
               wrap.add(w);
               i++;

          }
      }  

     else if(optionSelected=='StaticResource'){
            wrap=new List<WrapperClass>();
           type=optionSelected;

           system.debug('---Type----'+type);
          selectedObj=Database.query('SELECT Name,Id,BodyLength ,CreatedDate,Owner.Name from '+type);
          i=0;
          for(Sobject s:selectedObj)
          {
               WrapperClass w=new WrapperClass(type,i,false,s.id,s.Name,s.BodyLength);
               wrap.add(w);
               i++;

          }
      }  

    return null;
}



public Class WrapperClass
{
    public String type{get;set;}
    public integer index{get;set;}
    public Boolean Selecetd{get;set;}
    public ID id{get;set;}
    public String Fname{get;set;}
    public Integer sizeInKiloByte {get;set;}
    public Date Cdate {get;set;}
    public String CName{get;set;}



    public WrapperClass(String s,Integer i,Boolean b,ID iden,String n,Integer size)
    {
        type=s;
       Index=i;
        Selecetd=b;
        id=iden;
        Fname=n;
        sizeInKiloByte=size;


    }



}

}
```

Comment: Where?  Please try and help other people help you.  I'm assuming it's the `s.Name` in which case try `s.get('Name')`, and similar for the other fields.

Answer (score 4):

You issue is that you are assigning an sObject to the value of the var s:

```
for(Sobject s:selectedObj)
```

and are then attempting to the the field `name` by using a field expression

```
FileName=String.valueof(s.Name);
```

The only field expression for sObjects that can be used are id

```
s.id
```

for all other fields you must GET the value from the sObject class associated with the sObject as follows:

```
FileName=String.valueof(s.get('Name'));
```

or

```
FileName=(String)s.get('Name'));
```

Same goes for `s.BodyLength` where you use that and any other case except s.id

> get(field)
>
> Returns the value for the field specified by the field token
>   Schema.sObjectField, such as, Schema.Account.AccountNumber. Signature
>
> public Object get(Schema.sObjectField field)
>
> Parameters
>
> field Type: Schema.SObjectField Return Value
>
> Type: Object

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get_2